# Rails Layout name inside view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, view

How can I print out the name of current layout in a view?

Example

```
puts controller.current_layout
```

Thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails3 get current layout name inside view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326579/rails3-get-current-layout-name-inside-view)

Answer (score 10):

This works with Rails 3.0.7:

```
controller.send :_layout
```

Obviously, it's a private method, so use at your own risk.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me: response.layout

UPDATE:
True, response.layout does not work in rails3+ thus I usually define a @layout_name variable inside each layout.

Example of application.html.haml

```
- @layout_name = 'application'
!!! Strict
%html
...
```

Comment: this does not work on Rails 3.  `#layout` is now a private method inside `ActionDispatch::Response`

Answer (score 4):

`<%= controller.active_layout %>` gets you the layout file name. So `layout 'application'` would return `layouts/application.html.erb`

*In Rails 2.1.0 and greater*.

Comment: The problem when I want to set layout for an action like this "layout 'widget', :only => [:account, :verify]". In this case controller.active_layout always returns "widget". Fix?