# Rails3 get current layout name inside view

Tags: layout, view, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the answer for the Rails 2.X but not for Rails 3. How can I read the name of a current layout rendered inside a view.

My Rails2 question: [Rails Layout name inside view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622219/rails-layout-name-inside-view)

Thx.

Answer (score 17):

Getting this to work in Rails 3.2 is  a little more complicated than previously outlined.  If your controller explicitly declares a layout, then the result of `controller.send(:_layout)` is a String, but otherwise it's an ActionView::Template.  Try this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def current_layout
    layout = controller.send(:_layout)
    if layout.instance_of? String
      layout
    else
      File.basename(layout.identifier).split('.').first
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is wrong - it gets what the controller sets, but not one set with `render :layout`.

Answer (score 7):

in rails 5

This works for me:

```
def current_layout
  layout = controller.class.send(:_layout)
  if layout.nil?
    default_layout
  elsif layout.instance_of? String or layout.instance_of? Symbol
    layout
  else
    File.basename(layout.identifier).split('.').first
  end
end
```

Comment: The OP asked about a different version than what you are showing here. Are you sure that they will be comparable since apparently going from 2 to 3 is not.

Comment: This also worked for me on **Rails 5.0.1*** `controller.send(:_layout, [])`

Answer (score 6):

For Rails 4:

```
controller.send(:_layout)
=> 'application'
```

For Rails 3.2:

```
controller.send(:_layout)
=> #<ActionView::Template:0x000000082bb788>
```

But `controller.send(:_layout).identifier` returns the fullpath:

```
/home/davidm/Documentos/Devel/myapp/app/views/layouts/application.haml
```

Answer (score 5):

I think it should be in core, but for now you can make a helper method:

```
 def current_layout
    controller.send :_layout
  end
```

it will return currently used layout name

Comment: This is true in case you do not manually render a layout like this: render :layout => 'application'.

Answer (score 2):

I have used in Rails4 at view pages and got reuslt.

```
controller.send(:_layout)
```

I hope this help.[image]

Answer (score 1):

For rails 5:

```
controller.class.send(:_layout)
```

This does NOT work:

```
controller.send(:_layout)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what I've done in my [Ajax gem for Rails](http://github.com/kjvarga/ajax) which is to wrap the `_render_layout` method:

```
    ActionView::Base.class_eval do
      def _render_layout_with_tracking(layout, locals, &block)
        controller.instance_variable_set(:@_rendered_layout, layout)
        _render_layout_without_tracking(layout, locals, &block)
      end
      alias_method_chain :_render_layout, :tracking
    end
```

Then you can access the value that was set from your view (I'm pretty sure you have access to the controller there...) or in your controller in an `after_filter`, which is what I do.

I've written a [custom RSpec 2 matcher](http://kjvarga.blogspot.com/2011/05/rspec-2-matcher-to-test-layout.html) which can be used to test layout rendering in Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

All the approaches in the previous answers try to *guess* the name via private methods, but there's no need to guess and can be easily accomplished with the public API:

```
class ApplicationController
  layout :set_layout
  attr_reader :layout_name
  helper_method :layout_name

  private

  def set_layout
    @layout_name = "application"
  end
end
```

Override in any controller that won't use the standard layout:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  private

  def set_layout
    @layout_name = "my_layout"
  end
end
```

And now in your views:

```
<%= layout_name %>
```