# Rails 3: How to get the name of the current layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller I have:

```
render :layout => 'mobile'
```

In my view I want to be able to get the name of the layout, in this case "mobile".

I don't need the controller or action name...just the name of the layout.

I'm using Rails 3.0.6.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326579/rails3-get-current-layout-name-inside-view

Comment: @ZekeTemplin That doesn't work for me. In my example, using `:_layout` outputs `application`, not `mobile`.

Answer (score 11):

I was late, but try this:

> controller.send(:_layout).virtual_path.name

**Tested in Rails 3.2**

Answer (score 0):

why you dont make an variable in your controller:

```
@layout = 'mobile'
render :layout => @layout
```

then you can access `@layout` in your view

Comment: Because there's a better way to do that: `controller.send :_layout`.

Comment: @RyanBigg That doesn't work for me. In my example, using `:_layout` outputs `application`, not `mobile`.

Comment: It works as long as you do not manually render a layout like this: render :layout => 'mobile'