# testing a that Rails controller chooses a layout without rendering the layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, actioncontroller

i'd like to stub out render and i'd like to test that a certain layout is chosen

bonus catch: in the test env, that layout file will not exist

is there a clever way to detect if the controller has selected a layout without rendering, and without triggering an ActionView::MissingTemplate error?

(this is on a Rails 2.3 app, but feel free to chat rails 3)

Comment: Duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622219/rails-layout-name-inside-view

Comment: nope. :active_layout will throw ActionView::MissingTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is put your layout selection logic in a helper and test the helper directly.  No need to stub anything out or fake the rendering.

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base
  layout :choose_layout

private
  def choose_layout
    if some_thing?
      'this_layout'
    else
      'other_layout'
    end
  end
end

class MyControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "choose_layout" do
    @controller.stubs(:some_thing? => true)
    assert_equal 'other_layout', @controller.send(:choose_layout)
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks. i have an aversion to testing a private method like that, but it seems like that's what i've got to do in this case.

Comment: If calling the private method bothers you, you could encapsulate the functionality in a helper class and test that as a unit test.  Isolate the logic into a single responsibility piece of code and test that, that's the meta-answer.